# CryptoCurrency NODE.js Web3 Ethereum - Can't connect to TESTRPC

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, nodes

I am trying to connect to my testrpc instance from a my web3 application but I can't seem to connect. The below code should return an array of all the accounts in the testrpc chain.

Code:

```
Web3 = require('web3')
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
console.log(web3.eth.accounts);
```

It returns the below and inside the object intelliJ the currentprovider object is as follows.
[image]

It just seems to print the object I think:

```
Accounts {
  eth: 
   Eth {
     currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
     _requestManager: RequestManager { provider: [Object], providers: [Object], subscriptions: {} },
     givenProvider: null,
     providers: 
      { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
        HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
        IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
     _provider: HttpProvider { host: 'http://localhost:8545', timeout: 0, connected: false },
     setProvider: [Function],
     BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
     extend: 
      { [Function: ex]
        formatters: [Object],
        utils: [Object],
        Method: [Function: Method] },
     clearSubscriptions: [Function],
     getProtocolVersion: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_protocolVersion' },
     getCoinbase: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_coinbase' },
     isMining: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_mining' },
     getHashrate: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_hashrate' },
     isSyncing: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_syncing' },
     getGasPrice: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_gasPrice' },
     getAccounts: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_accounts' },
     getBlockNumber: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_blockNumber' },
     getBalance: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getBalance' },
     getStorageAt: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getStorageAt' },
     getCode: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getCode' },
     getBlock: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: [Function: blockCall] },
     getUncle: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: [Function: uncleCall] },
     getCompilers: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getCompilers' },
     getBlockTransactionCount: 
      { [Function: send]
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: [Function: getBlockTransactionCountCall] },
     getBlockUncleCount: 
      { [Function: send]
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: [Function: uncleCountCall] },
     getTransaction: 
      { [Function: send]
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'eth_getTransactionByHash' },
     getTransactionFromBlock: 
      { [Function: send]
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: [Function: transactionFromBlockCall] },
     getTransactionReceipt: 
      { [Function: send]
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'eth_getTransactionReceipt' },
     getTransactionCount: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getTransactionCount' },
     call: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_call' },
     estimateGas: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_estimateGas' },
     sendSignedTransaction: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_sendRawTransaction' },
     signTransaction: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_signTransaction' },
     sendTransaction: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_sendTransaction' },
     sign: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_sign' },
     compile: { solidity: [Object], lll: [Object], serpent: [Object] },
     submitWork: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_submitWork' },
     getWork: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getWork' },
     getPastLogs: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getLogs' },
     subscribe: { [Function] call: undefined },
     net: 
      Net {
        currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
        _requestManager: [Object],
        givenProvider: null,
        providers: [Object],
        _provider: [Object],
        setProvider: [Function],
        BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
        extend: [Object],
        getId: [Object],
        isListening: [Object],
        getPeerCount: [Object],
        getNetworkType: [Function: bound getNetworkType] },
     accounts: [Circular],
     personal: 
      Personal {
        currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
        _requestManager: [Object],
        givenProvider: null,
        providers: [Object],
        _provider: [Object],
        setProvider: [Function],
        BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
        extend: [Object],
        getAccounts: [Object],
        newAccount: [Object],
        unlockAccount: [Object],
        sendTransaction: [Object],
        lockAccount: [Object],
        importRawKey: [Object],
        sign: [Object],
        ecRecover: [Object],
        net: [Object] },
     Contract: [Function: Contract],
     Iban: 
      { [Function: Iban]
        toAddress: [Function],
        toIban: [Function],
        fromAddress: [Function],
        fromBban: [Function],
        createIndirect: [Function],
        isValid: [Function] },
     abi: ABICoder { _types: [Array] } },
  wallet: 
   Wallet {
     length: 0,
     _accounts: [Circular],
     defaultKeyName: 'web3js_wallet' } }
```

The testRPC server starts successfully too:
[image]

Comment: Did you try if other commands do work?

Answer (score 18):

If you are using the new web3.js 1.0.0-beta, then try this (all the syntax has changed, sigh). Tested with `testrpc -d`.

```
> var Web3 = require('web3');
> var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');
> web3.version;
'1.0.0-beta.11'
> web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);
Promise { ... }
> [ '0x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C1',
  '0xFFcf8FDEE72ac11b5c542428B35EEF5769C409f0',
  '0x22d491Bde2303f2f43325b2108D26f1eAbA1e32b',
  '0xE11BA2b4D45Eaed5996Cd0823791E0C93114882d',
  '0xd03ea8624C8C5987235048901fB614fDcA89b117',
  '0x95cED938F7991cd0dFcb48F0a06a40FA1aF46EBC',
  '0x3E5e9111Ae8eB78Fe1CC3bb8915d5D461F3Ef9A9',
  '0x28a8746e75304c0780E011BEd21C72cD78cd535E',
  '0xACa94ef8bD5ffEE41947b4585a84BdA5a3d3DA6E',
  '0x1dF62f291b2E969fB0849d99D9Ce41e2F137006e' ]
```

Absolutely everything is asynchronous now, hence the messing about with promises with the like of the `.then` method.  I've spent the last day grappling with this - it's very strange at first, but is improving with familiarity.

If you want the accounts in a variable, you can do it like this, but take care not to use the variable until the promise is resolved.

```
> var foo;
> web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accts => {foo = accts});
> foo
[ '0x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C1',
  '0xFFcf8FDEE72ac11b5c542428B35EEF5769C409f0',
  '0x22d491Bde2303f2f43325b2108D26f1eAbA1e32b',
  '0xE11BA2b4D45Eaed5996Cd0823791E0C93114882d',
  '0xd03ea8624C8C5987235048901fB614fDcA89b117',
  '0x95cED938F7991cd0dFcb48F0a06a40FA1aF46EBC',
  '0x3E5e9111Ae8eB78Fe1CC3bb8915d5D461F3Ef9A9',
  '0x28a8746e75304c0780E011BEd21C72cD78cd535E',
  '0xACa94ef8bD5ffEE41947b4585a84BdA5a3d3DA6E',
  '0x1dF62f291b2E969fB0849d99D9Ce41e2F137006e' ]
```

Comment: when that was changed?

Comment: I don't know exactly - I think v.1.0.0 became the default `npm` install within the last couple of weeks. You can install the old stable version with `npm install web3@0.20.0`, but it looks like the future lies with this, so I reckon it's worth getting to grips with.

Comment: Yay, this saved me! Been trying to figure this out for a while now. They really need to update their docs if the syncronous functions are going to no longer work.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

Comment: For regular JS: `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(accts) { console.log(accts); })`

Comment: This also works and is briefer, which is handy when working at the console: `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log)`.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code and it seems to work. I also used testrpc.

`yourscript.js`

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
console.log(web3.eth.accounts);

if(web3.isConnected())
    console.log("ok");
```

The accounts are correctly logged with the output `ok`.
Have you tried to run the command `node yourscript.js`?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug from the latest release of web3. npm install grabs 1.0.0-beta, which is not the stable release (0.20.0).

Reinstall with

`npm uninstall web3`

`npm install web3@0.20.1 --save`

Then try again. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to check with `truffle console`?

Also check if anything is being logged in testrpc console after execution.

I would suggest restart your testrpc as nothing seems wrong your code and it is working perfectly for me also.